# enumerate-graphic-types is empty, unable to use graphics [MIT/GNU Scheme]

Tags: graphics, scheme, mit-scheme

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and MIT-Scheme's procedure `(enumerate-graphic-types)` returns nothing. Even compiling the software from source with the flags `--include-x11` and `--with-x` simply tells me that lib/*.com does not exist in my /usr/bin/install directory.

I am not sure how to compile/run scheme so I can use its graphical procedures.

Comment: *enumerate-graphics-types*

Answer (score 1):

```
(enumerate-graphics-types) ; void
(load-option 'x11)
(enumerate-graphics-types) ; non-void
(define dev (make-graphics-device 'x))
```

This should work, supposing you compiled with the appropriate autotools flags.

```
1 ]=>  (enumerate-graphics-types)

;Value: ()

1 ]=> (load-option 'x11)

;Loading "make.scm"...
;  Loading "x11-unx.pkd"... done
;  Loading "x11-base.com"... done
;  Loading "x11-color.com"... done
;  Loading "x11-graphics.com"... done
;  Loading "x11-device.com"... done
;  Loading "x11-terminal.com"... done
;... done
;Value: x11

1 ]=>  (enumerate-graphics-types)

;Value: (x)
```